# Akka Persistence: Where do the execution of the Command Goes when it is not simply a state update

Tags: scala, akka-persistence

Just for clarification: Where do the execution of a command goes, when the execution is not simply a state update (like in most examples found online)

For instance, in my case,

- The *Command* is **FetchLastHistoryChangeSet** which consist in fetching the last history changeset from an external service based on where we left off last time. In other words the time of the newest change of the previous history ChangeSet Fetched.
- The *Event* would be **HistoryChangeSetFetched(changeSet, time)**. In correlation to what has been said above, the time should be that of the newest change of the newly history ChangeSet Fetched (as per the command event currently being handled)

Now in all example that i see, it is always: (i) *validating the command*, then, (ii) *persisting the event*, and finally (iii) *handling the event*.

It is in *handling the event* that i have seen custom code added in addition to the updatestate logic. Where, the custom code is usually added after the update state function. But this custom is most of the time about sending message back to the sender, or broadcasting it to the event bus.

As per my example, it is clear that i need to do quite few operation to actually call  ***Persist*(HistoryChangeSetFetched(changeSet, time))**. Indeed i need the new changeset, and the time of the newest change of it.

The only way i see it possible is to do the fetch in the *validating the command*

That is:

```
case FetchLastHistoryChangeSet => val changetuple = if ValidateCommand(FetchLastHistoryChangeSet) persit(HistoryChangeSetFetched(changetuple._1, changetuple._2)) { historyChangeSetFetched =>
  updateState(historyChangeSetFetched)
}
```

Where the ValidateCommand(FetchLastHistoryChangeSet)

would have as logic, to read last changeSet time (newest change of the changeSet), fetch a new changeset based on it, if it exist, get the time of its newest change, and return the tuple.

> My question is, is that how it is supposed to work. Validating command
>   can be something as complex as that ? i.e. actually executing the
>   command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the documentation: "validation can mean anything, from simple inspection of a command message's fields up to a conversation with several external services"

So I think what you're trying to do is exactly right. Any interaction with an external service must be done at the command validation stage.